# objects cannot be displayed sometimes

Tags: html, css, silverlight, internet-explorer

I used the following code:

```
<DIV style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 24px" id="_sizing__c_TarPro"> 
  <DIV style="Z-INDEX: 0; POSITION: relative; BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; HEIGHT: 24px" id="_slot__c_TarPro"> 
   <object id="sl__c_TarPro" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%"> 
    <param name="source" value="xxxxxx.xap&xxxxIgnoreNotFound=true"></param> 
       <param name="onload" value="onSilverlightLoad" /> 
       <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" /> 
       <param name="background" value="transparent" /> 
       <param name="windowless" value="true" /> 
       <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50401.0" /> 
       <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" /> 
       <param name="Culture" value="EN" /> 
       <param name="UICulture" value="EN" /> 
    <param name="initParams" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
         dimension=DIMENSION4,
         defaultValue=,
         dimensionDescription=,
         allowMultipleSelection=TRUE,
         allowLeafSelection=TRUE,
         allowParentSelection=TRUE,
         allowReadAccessSelection=TRUE,
         attributeFilter=,
         symbolSpec=DIM4SET,
         targetVariable=_c_TarPro"/> 
         width=200,
         height=24,
         <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156" style="text-decoration: none"> 
           <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none"></img> 
         </a> 
   </object> 
   <input id="_c_TarPro" name="_c_TarPro" style="display:none" value=""/> 
 </DIV> 
</DIV>
```

Repeat this code for several objects, sometimes these objects are displayed. But sometimes few objects are displayed and others are not displayed after refresh. It is random the number of objects are displayed.
This only happens on IE8 and IE9. (Sorry before I said on IE9 it works well because QA reports that, but I tested on IE9 and see the same issue.)

Anybody has idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is the cause of your issue, but the **width** and **height** that you apply to `<param name="initParams">` are declared outside the tag, which might prevent those attributes from being interpreted.

You've got:

```
<param name="initParams" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
     dimension=DIMENSION4,
     defaultValue=,
     dimensionDescription=,
     allowMultipleSelection=TRUE,
     allowLeafSelection=TRUE,
     allowParentSelection=TRUE,
     allowReadAccessSelection=TRUE,
     attributeFilter=,
     symbolSpec=DIM4SET,
     targetVariable=_c_TarPro"/> 
     <!-- what are these guys doing outside the tag? -->
     width=200,
     height=24,
```

Comment: Thanks stephen, I tried to put width and height inside the tag, but no change. Still some objects are displayed and others are not after every refresh. And sometimes even no object are displayed.